# Solve $\sin(x)-\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}-x)=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

As in the title, solve $\sin(x)-\sin(\frac{\pi}{3}-x)=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$. I was trying to rewrite it into a simpler form, but without any luck.

Comment: Are you sure the second term shouldn't be $-\sin(\frac\pi3-x)$ instead?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Good point, I guess it is.

Comment: Did you try to apply the formula for $\sin A - \sin B$?

Comment: Hint: expand $\sin(\pi/3 - x)$ by using the formula $\sin(\alpha - \beta) = \sin\alpha\cos\beta - \cos\alpha\sin\beta$.

Comment: My calculator gives: for every integer $n$, $\pi n + \sqrt{3}/2$ and $\pi n - \sqrt{3}/2$

Comment: RHS might be $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ instead of $\sqrt{\frac 32}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\sin(x)-\sin(\frac\pi3-x) = \sin(x)+\sin(x-\frac\pi3) = \sqrt3 \sin(x-\frac\pi6) $$
(draw a sketch for the latter identity, using the parallelogram rule to add the two sines).

So now you want to solve $\sin(x-\pi/6) = 1/\sqrt2$, which gives $$x-\frac\pi6 = (2\pm 1)\frac\pi4$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin(x)-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}-x\right)=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sin(x)-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}+x\right)=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{3\sin(x)}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\cos(x)=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-\sqrt{3}\left(\frac{\cos(x)}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\sin(x)\right)=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-\sqrt{3}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\cos(x)-\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)\sin(x)\right)=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-\sqrt{3}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-x\right)=\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-x\right)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\pi}{6}-x=\frac{5\pi}{4}+2\pi n_1\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space\frac{\pi}{6}-x=\frac{7\pi}{4}+2\pi n_2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-x=\frac{13\pi}{12}+2\pi n_1\Longleftrightarrow\space\space\vee\space\space -x=\frac{19\pi}{12}+2\pi n_2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=-\frac{13\pi}{12}-2\pi n_1\space\space\vee\space\space x=-\frac{19\pi}{12}+2\pi n_2$$

With $n_1,n_2\in\mathbb{Z}$